# Different Order Success Mail for Selected Category

Tags: category, email-templates

When a customer purchase a `selected category products` , then the `order success mail` should be `different`

I wants to customize `the order status mail for selected category` only, for other categories default mail should send.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and override Mage_Sales_Model_Order 's action sendNewOrderEmail(). There you'll be able to test if your condition is true or not, and send a different mail template to customers according to that.

**Edit:**

Where it says

```
$mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId));
$mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
if(/*Your custom condition on category is true*/)
    $mailer->setTemplateId('your_custom_template_id_in_magento_backend);
else
    $mailer->setTemplateId($templateId); //using the default temaplte id, given upper in Magento code.
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
    'myparam1' => 'my value1',
            'myparam2' => 'my value2'
    )
);
$mailer->send();
```

Comment: can you tell where to add the condition

Comment: I've edited my answer to best answer your question.